# After the Heartbleed bug, do we need to update our OpenSSL DLL's?

Tags: openssl, dll, development, heartbleed

Our software we develop uses the Indy internet component suite in Delphi. Indy has capabilities for OpenSSL. Since the Heartbleed incident, we're wondering if we need to take action.

We distribute 2 DLL's with our software which are for OpenSSL (which Indy uses): `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`.

Question: Do we need to get and distribute updated/fixed versions of these DLL's? Or will this be patched with Windows Updates?

This is using Indy version 10, and the DLL's don't have any version information, just shows 1.0.0.0 and a date of 9/20/2010.

Essentially, is the problem on the software level or the operating system level?

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  You don't indicate what version of OpenSSL your using only certain versions are vulnerable.   Only you can determine if your using a vulnerable version.  If you are it means that you should revoke the certificates after you update the client.

Comment: I honestly know nothing about it, just that Indy has it integrated into it and an Indy component we use requires these DLL's. Also, the version doesn't matter with my question. I'm basically asking is the problem exposed in any version of any OpenSLL implementation, or is it something in Windows.

Comment: You need to determine all of that before we can help.  You can't just simply update the files, if this component except a certain version, it will no longer work.

Comment: @Ramhound I know I can't just replace the files. Please see the edits in my question. What really matters is whether the issue requires fixes in the application or the operating system.

Comment: Your edits don't provide the information I required to answer the question.  If you are asking "or the operating system" it means you don't understand the `Heartbleed` bug.

Comment: Of course I don't understand it, that's why I'm asking about it...

Comment: Well your question isn't about the bug.  Your asking if your software that uses an unknown version of the OpenSSL library needs to be updated to include a version of the OpenSSL library that isn't vulnerable to this bug.  **I can't answer that question because you have not been able to provide that information when asked for it.**  I have no idea what operating system your using.  Windows itself not use OpenSSL for anything.  OS X while it distributes a vulnerable version, OS X itself does not actually use it, and the library itself was depreciated awhile ago.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked this in a more programming oriented site which knows about Indy, I know Stack Overflow wouldn't have been the right place to ask this.

Comment: Your still going to need to be able to tell us what version of the OpenSSL library the specific version of Indy your using is compiled again.  We can't tell you if your vulnerable without that information.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with "Heartbleed bug" will be on the server side (websites).
Though clients are affected too, it is much less possible that someone will misuse that.

You can use Indy original SSL distribution from
http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/
You can find "openssl-1.0.1g" here which are the latest and fixed libraries.
It should be fully compatible with Indy. You can just replace files and forget about this problem.